# JHipster - How to compile SCSS files directly with angular 7

Tags: jhipster, angular7

Normaly it is really easy to add SCSS styles to components with angular components (just create the scss file and import it in the component.ts), however this styles are not rendered to normal css files, the styles are embeded (from what i understand, i am very new with angular).

This creates a problem, i am trying to use a [theme with some dinamic skins](https://uxpowered.com/products/appwork/v121/angular-demo/dashboards/dashboard-1) with a "*customization panel*", but this component needs the path to my compiled css indepedently.

To achieve this, in the vendor basic app, i can see they added this to the `angular.js`:

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "angular-starter": {
      ...,
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-starter",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",

              { "input": "src/vendor/styles/appwork.scss", "bundleName": "vendor/styles/appwork", "lazy": true },
              { "input": "src/vendor/styles/appwork-material.scss", "bundleName": "vendor/styles/appwork-material", "lazy": true },
              { "input": "src/vendor/styles/bootstrap.scss", "bundleName": "vendor/styles/bootstrap", "lazy": true },
              { "input": "src/vendor/styles/bootstrap-material.scss", "bundleName": "vendor/styles/bootstrap-material", "lazy": true },
              // More styles like this
            ],
            ...
```

And then it can be referenced directly as css file, as the index shows:

```
<html lang="en" class="default-style">
  <head>
    ...
    <!-- Here it references the compiled scss as css directly -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/styles/bootstrap.css" class="theme-settings-bootstrap-css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/styles/appwork.css" class="theme-settings-appwork-css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/styles/theme-corporate.css" class="theme-settings-theme-css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/styles/colors.css" class="theme-settings-colors-css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/styles/uikit.css">

    ...
    <script>
      // Here uses the path of the compiled css as parameter,
      // this way the skin selector changes the css used in the page
      window.themeSettings = new ThemeSettings({
        cssPath: 'vendor/styles/',
        themesPath: 'vendor/styles/'
      });
    </script>

  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

## However

Cheking the angular.js generated from jhipster, i can see the architect part is empty:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "consuldent": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src/main/webapp",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {}
        }
    },
```

I do not know if this is because in the example code it uses `ng serve` to run the demo page, using a node.js server, where jhipster uses spring directly, i tried adding the styles part to the jhipster's angular.js file, but i can not find any route where the css could be loaded, so im guessing it is just ignoring the code that i added

Comment: Have you tried adding the files to vendor.scss (or vendor.css if you don't use SCSS)?  For example here: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/21af1441005f52cf1c0fd1c598f722b2ebb6c2d9/src/main/webapp/content/css/vendor.css

Comment: The problem is that the plugin needs the route to the .css files, if i add the files to the vendor, they are compiled and included, but i have no access to the routes for the "new ThemeSettings({ cssPath: 'vendor/styles/', themesPath: 'vendor/styles/'});"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In angular, the view is encapsulated with each unique attribute.

add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in main component, hence the css will be shared by all components

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular app';
}
```

---

Jhipster uses webpack to pack the angular modules. You want to bundle the *css* hence 
copy your css into **/src/main/webapp/vendor/styles/appwork.css**'
add an entry in `webpack.common.js`

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/css', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/css' },
    { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/lib', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/lib' },
    { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.min.js', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.min.js' },
    { from: './src/main/webapp/swagger-ui/', to: 'swagger-ui' },
    { from: './src/main/webapp/content/', to: 'content' },        
    { from: './src/main/webapp/vendor/styles/appwork.css', to: 'content/vendor/styles/appwork.css' },    
    { from: './src/main/webapp/favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico' },
    { from: './src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp', to: 'manifest.webapp' },
    // jhipster-needle-add-assets-to-webpack - JHipster will add/remove third-party resources in this array
    { from: './src/main/webapp/robots.txt', to: 'robots.txt' }
]),
```

---

To compile custom sass

Add the entry in **webpack.prod.js** , for example **myfile** and **myfile2**. Then change the sass compiler to include our myfile.scss, myfile2.scss, finally comment the MiniCssExtractPlugin

```
    entry: {
    polyfills: './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
    global: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss',
    myfile: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/myfile.scss',
    myfile2: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/myfile2.scss',
    main: './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
  },
 .
 .
 .
 .
  exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss|myfile\.scss|myfile2\.scss)/
 .
 .
 .
 .
 test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss|myfile\.scss|myfile2\.scss)/ 
 .
 .
 .
 .
 exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css|myfile\.css|myfile2\.css)/
 .
 .
 .
 .
 test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css|myfile\.css|myfile2\.css)/,
 .
 .
 .
 .
     new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
        // both options are optional
       // filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
        // chunkFilename: '[id].css'
    }),
```

**Your webpack.prod.js file look like this**

```
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
    const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
    const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
    const Visualizer = require('webpack-visualizer-plugin');
    const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');
    const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
    const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
    const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
    const path = require('path');

    const utils = require('./utils.js');
    const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

    const ENV = 'production';
    const sass = require('sass');

    module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
        // Enable source maps. Please note that this will slow down the build.
        // You have to enable it in UglifyJSPlugin config below and in tsconfig-aot.json as well
        // devtool: 'source-map',
        entry: {
            polyfills: './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
            global: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss',
            myfile: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/myfile.scss',
            myfile2: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/myfile2.scss',
            main: './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
        },
        output: {
            path: utils.root('build/www'),
            filename: 'app/[name].[hash].bundle.js',
            chunkFilename: 'app/[id].[hash].chunk.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: { implementation: sass }
                }],
                exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss|myfile\.scss|myfile2\.scss)/
            },
            {
                test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss|myfile\.scss|myfile2\.scss)/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: { implementation: sass }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
                exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css|myfile\.css|myfile2\.css)/
            },
            {
                test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css|myfile\.css|myfile2\.css)/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            }]
        },
        optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: false,
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    commons: {
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        name: 'vendors',
                        chunks: 'all'
                    }
                }
            },
            minimizer: [
                new TerserPlugin({
                    parallel: true,
                    cache: true,
                    terserOptions: {
                        ie8: false,
                        // sourceMap: true, // Enable source maps. Please note that this will slow down the build
                        compress: {
                            dead_code: true,
                            warnings: false,
                            properties: true,
                            drop_debugger: true,
                            conditionals: true,
                            booleans: true,
                            loops: true,
                            unused: true,
                            toplevel: true,
                            if_return: true,
                            inline: true,
                            join_vars: true
                        },
                        output: {
                            comments: false,
                            beautify: false,
                            indent_level: 2
                        }
                    }
                }),
                new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
             new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                 // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
                 // both options are optional
                // filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
                 // chunkFilename: '[id].css'
             }),
            new MomentLocalesPlugin({
                localesToKeep: [
                        'en',
                        'es'
                        // jhipster-needle-i18n-language-moment-webpack - JHipster will add/remove languages in this array
                    ]
            }),
            new Visualizer({
                // Webpack statistics in target folder
                filename: '../stats.html'
            }),
            new AngularCompilerPlugin({
                mainPath: utils.root('src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts'),
                tsConfigPath: utils.root('tsconfig-aot.json'),
                sourceMap: true
            }),
            new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                minimize: true,
                debug: false
            }),
            new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
              clientsClaim: true,
              skipWaiting: true,
            })
        ],
        mode: 'production'
    });
```

similarly do the same step for **webpack.dev.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const writeFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');
const SimpleProgressWebpackPlugin = require('simple-progress-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const path = require('path');
const sass = require('sass');

const utils = require('./utils.js');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const ENV = 'development';

module.exports = (options) => webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './build/www',
        proxy: [{
            context: [
                /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
                '/api',
                '/management',
                '/swagger-resources',
                '/v2/api-docs',
                '/h2-console',
                '/auth'
            ],
            target: `http${options.tls ? 's' : ''}://127.0.0.1:8080`,
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: options.tls,
            headers: { host: 'localhost:9000' }
        }],
        stats: options.stats,
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/
        }
    },
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
        global: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss',
        myfile: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/myfile.scss',
        myfile2: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/myfile2.scss',
        main: './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
    },
    output: {
        path: utils.root('build/www'),
        filename: 'app/[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'app/[id].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            enforce: 'pre',
            loader: 'tslint-loader',
            exclude: [/(node_modules)/, new RegExp('reflect-metadata\\' + path.sep + 'Reflect\\.ts')]
        },
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: [
                'angular2-template-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'cache-loader',
                    options: {
                      cacheDirectory: path.resolve('build/cache-loader')
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'thread-loader',
                    options: {
                        // there should be 1 cpu for the fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
                        workers: require('os').cpus().length - 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    options: {
                        transpileOnly: true,
                        happyPackMode: true
                    }
                },
                'angular-router-loader'
            ],
            exclude: /(node_modules)/
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: { implementation: sass }
            }],
            exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss|myfile\.scss|myfile2\.scss)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss|myfile\.scss|myfile2\.scss)/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: { implementation: sass }
            }]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
            exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css|myfile\.css|myfile2\.css)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css|myfile\.css|myfile2\.css)/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }]
    },
    stats: process.env.JHI_DISABLE_WEBPACK_LOGS ? 'none' : options.stats,
    plugins: [
        process.env.JHI_DISABLE_WEBPACK_LOGS
            ? null
            : new SimpleProgressWebpackPlugin({
                format: options.stats === 'minimal' ? 'compact' : 'expanded'
              }),
        new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 9000,
            proxy: {
                target: 'http://localhost:9060'
            },
            socket: {
                clients: {
                    heartbeatTimeout: 60000
                }
            }
        }, {
            reload: false
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)/,
            path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp')
        ),
        new writeFilePlugin(),
        new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
            utils.root('src/test'),
        ]),
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
            title: 'JHipster',
            contentImage: path.join(__dirname, 'logo-jhipster.png')
        })
    ].filter(Boolean),
    mode: 'development'
});
```

Then if you want the css to be include in your index.html then change the **webpack.common.js**

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/main/webapp/index.html',
    chunks: ['vendors', 'polyfills', 'main', 'global','myfile','myfile2'],
    chunksSortMode: 'manual',
    inject: 'body'
})
```

Comment: Ok, i tried to understand the second approach, i checked the webpack.common.js file and i think this is the best way, but i have a little problem, the files of the layout are .scss so they need to be compiled first, i did not find some place to do this, where can i add the paths so webpack compiles them, so i can add the files to the webpack.common.js file

Comment: Ok i think this is just what i need, i will check today in the night and let you know, thanks a lot for such detailed answer!!!

Comment: I have verified using jhipster 5.8.1, updated the webpack.prod.js `MiniCssExtractPlugin` is needed , just comment the options alone instead of removing.

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom styles to src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss